# Stop %JAVA_HOME% being expanded when getting PATH environmental variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

The following code gets and prints out my environmental variables in PATH:

```
$path_variables =  (Get-ChildItem Env:PATH | Select-Object -first 1).Value
Write-Host $path_variables
```

But the problem is, the variable `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is translated to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` when it is printed out.

Is there a way to keep the dynamic nature of the variable when grabbing it with powershell?

Comment: What's the reason for this requirement? I assume it'll be changed to the full path at some point?

Comment: The environment does not know how the variable was created; it only knows the resulting value. I suppose you could dredge through the registry for the system and user environment variable settings, but that might or might not be worthwhile.

Comment: the requirement is that I am running a script that reverts environmental variables to their previous value after installing a feature.  I would like to keep the dynamic nature of the variables when they are reverted

Comment: When the shell running the script exits, the original values will be there. If you are saying that the script is changing the value of the JAVA_HOME variable, it will have to do that in the registry for the next process to get it.